# Segmentation fault on sscanf in C

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

Very new to C so please bear with me! I'm trying to read 3 arguments separated by spaces from "instruction" into the 3 strings using sscanf. I've got the following code so far:

```
char * buffer;
buffer = (char*) malloc (5000);
sscanf(instruction, "%s %s %s", &opcode, &arg1, &arg2, buffer);
```

However whilst it compiles fine, there is a seg fault on the last line where the sscanf is. Last time I saw this error it was because there wasn't enough memory in the variables to store the information. I'm guessing I'm not using malloc properly?

I can't post the entire code unfortunately as it doesn't belong to me.

Comment: What's the types of `opcode`, `arg1` and `arg2`? I guess the problem is there.

Comment: Then remove the ampersands. The three `%s` escapes will then fill them (assuming you have them pointing to valid memory and the buffers are large enough). Note the `buffer` will be never filled as your format strings refers only to three args.

Comment: Thanks - just done that. It's still seg faulting on that line though - do I need to allocate memory to one of the variables?

Comment: First off, you need to SHOW us how you declared those variables, and any earlier operations you did (such as allocating memory, or clearing them out).

Comment: also, how is `instruction` populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sscanf` improperly. Try this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024 /* generally good practice to use constants */

char *opcode = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
char *arg1 = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
char *arg2 = (char *)malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
sscanf(instruction, "%s %s %s", opcode, arg1, arg2);
```

Depending on how you use these variables, it might be better to allocate them on the stack:

```
char opcode[BUFFER_SIZE];
char arg1[BUFFER_SIZE];
char arg2[BUFFER_SIZE];
sscanf(instruction, "%s %s %s", opcode, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much. Will tick the answer in 3 minutes.

Comment: @JamesHadley: Don't forget to call `free()` to free the memory allocated by `malloc()` :)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the ampersands. The three `%s` escapes will then fill them (assuming you have them pointing to valid memory and the buffers are large enough). Note the buffer will be never filled as your format strings refers only to three args